# str_replace between first and second occurence

Tags: php

I want to make a function  PHP to replace the Text Like this example

`yyyy $XXXXXX$ zzzzz` replace with `yyyy <img src="XXXXXXXX" title="XXXXXXXX"/>  zzzzz`

Comment: Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: ... With an expression like `/\$([^\$]+)\$/` to capture into `$1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a REGEX for it ( [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) ) :

```
$str = 'yyyy $XXXXXX$ zzzzz';
$str = preg_replace('/\$([^$]+)\$/', '<img src="$1" title="$1"/>', $str);
```

edited with the help of : [cryptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1592648/cryptic)

Comment: There is no such thing as a `'g'` modifier for PCRE in PHP, and what happens when the string is `'yyyy $XXXXXX$ $1.00 zzzzz'`? It should be: `'/\$([^$]+)\$/'`